# $p$-group with a cyclic subgroup

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups, cyclic-groups, p-groups

Throughout studying a  paper about finite $p$-groups,
I have the following question

Let $G$ be a finite $p$-group with nilpotency class 3 and $\gamma_i(G)$ denote
the i'th term of the lower central series of $G$. Let $\gamma_3(G)$ has prime order and $\displaystyle\frac{G}{\gamma_3(G)}\cong M(p^n), n\geq 3$,
where $M(p^n)$ denotes the modular $p$-group with the following presentation
$$\langle a, b| a^{p^{n-1}}=b^{p}=1, [a,b]=a^{p^{n-2}}\rangle,$$ where $p$ is a prime
and $n\geq 3$   if $p$ is odd, $n\geq 4$ otherwise.
Obviously $M(p^n)$ has a cyclic subgroup of index $p$ (say $\langle a\rangle$).

Is it true that $G$ has a cyclic subgroup of index $p$?

Any answer will be appreciated!

Comment: R.J. Miech, *On $p$-groups with a cyclic commutator subgroup*, J. Austral. Math. Soc. **20** (1975) no. 2, 178-198 classifies all 2-generator $p$-groups with cyclic commutator subgroup.  You should look there.

Comment: Dear professor magidin, many thanks for your guidance.